# How to get all clients all payment transactions using laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My code is:

App\Models\Client.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
 protected $guarded = ['id'];
 
public function transactions()
 {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Transaction','clients_id');
 }

}
```

App\Models\Transaction.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Transaction extends Model
{
 protected $guarded = ['id'];
 
public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Client','clients_id');
    }

}
```

In controller i tried

```
use App\Models\Client;
use App\Models\Transaction;
```

`Client::with('transactions')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();`

but it's not working as expected

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the result of Client::with('transactions')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

Comment: please add table columns to make sure you did the right thing

Comment: It returns all of the clients despite having zero transaction records also no transaction info like transaction.amount ,transaction.transaction_date returned

Answer (score 0):

To get all clients in desc order with your transactions using

```
$clients = Client::with('transactions')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

returns all clients which has 1 or more transactions. By your mention in above comments **"It returns all of the clients despite having zero transaction records"** below query will not do that

```
$clients = Client::has('transactions')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

or

```
$clients = Client::has('transactions', '>=', 0)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get(); // you can add any number in place of zero
```

It is all given in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)